# Reading multiple xml files in php

Tags: php

I have 30 android clients that send xml files to the server every one hour.I need to read each file which is pretty long(over 1700 lines per file) but i am not so sure how reliable is for this kind of tasks.

Should i continue reading with php or is  C++ or java program better suited.

Answer (score 2):

With PHP you can use 2 good library: SimpleXML for simple functions or DOM for something more complexe.

You can have a idea of what PHP can do with XML files here: https://www.php.net/manual/en/refs.xml.php

If you know the names of nodes you need to read, SimpleXML is the simple way to manage yours datas. You actually can do what you want with XML files on PHP.